# How to change character strings to date time strings in r?

Tags: r, excel, csv, datetime, character

I have been trying to change character strings to date time strings that i would be able to create good plots and time series clustering. Somehow im just not able to change it. One possible problems is that my file is scv format and it somehow doesn't want to save changes to time format as date.

Here is few ways that i have tried to do this:

###############################################trying to change date time format

data666 = dataset %>% as_datetime(dataset$sts, tz = "UTC")

data$sts <- as.POSIXlt(dataset$sts, format = '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S', tz = "UTC")

dataset$sts <- dmy_hms(dataset$sts)

dataset$sts %>%
as_datetime(dataset$sts, "%Y%b%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")

data$sts = as.numeric(dataset$sts)

tz(dataset$sts)

as_datetime(dataset$ï..tst, tz = "UTC", format = NULL)

str(dataset)
'data.frame':   744 obs. of  7864 variables:
$ tst                : chr  "2019-01-01 00:00" "2019-01-01 01:00" "2019-01-01 02:00" "2019-01-01 03:00" ...
$ ESU000_7531131009  : chr  "0,001" "0,001" "0,001" "0,001" ...
$ ESU000_7534016002  : chr  "0,260" "0,260" "0,260" "0,270" ...
$ ESU000_7532142010  : chr  "0,000" "0,000" "0,000" "0,000" ...
$ ESU000_7534007001  : chr  "0,000" "0,000" "0,000" "0,000" ...
$ ESU000_7530814021  : chr  "0,370" "0,360" "0,370" "0,360"

As you can see structure of my dataset is not so well. But in excel it ok. I have understanded that this is the best format to have it for timeseries data clustering.
[In this format my excel shows it and also if i press it open from enviroment panel.][1]

I am doing my masters thesis on this subject and would really appreciate if someone, could help me little bit for right direction, because i have tried to solve this now for a week.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rict1.png

Comment: I forgot to tell that most of times those code lines just change my date time values to NA

Comment: This is a typo, you forgot the minuses in `format=`. Try `as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="UTC")`.